# How do I get asp:Label to take up space before having text assigned

Tags: asp.net, css

I have 2 buttons that need to be on the right hand side of a form and have a label on the right. The problem I am running into is that once the action has been performed, the label will read "successfully ...." or "error couldn't..." and it screws up my layout. when the form first appears it screws up my button layouts because the label is empty, then when the action has been performed, my label gets populated with text and then pushes my buttons into the right place. Is there a way to to keep my buttons in place?

Here is my layout:

```
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="dropDownList" style="position: relative;" runat="server">
                    <label>
                        Select New File:
                    </label>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCaseFiles" DataSourceID="dsMyCaseFiles" DataTextField="Display"
                        DataValueField="FileID" OnPreRender="ddl_PreRender" Width="524px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCaseFiles_SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlCaseFiles"
                        ToolTip="Casefile Required" InitialValue="-1" Text="*" Display="Dynamic" />
                    <ajaxToolkit:ListSearchExtender ID="ddlExtCaseFiles" runat="server" PromptCssClass="ListSearchExtenderPrompt"
                        TargetControlID="ddlCaseFiles" BehaviorID="ddlExtCaseFiles" Enabled="True" />
                    <br />
/////////////////////////area of interest
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Style="position: relative;
                        float: left; margin-left: 450px;" OnClientClick="parent.$.fancybox.close();" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnMoveCaseFile" runat="server" Text="" Style="position: relative;
                        float: right; margin-right: 63px; margin-left: -45px; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 98px;"
                        OnClick="btnMoveCaseFile_Click" />
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStatus"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
///////////////////////////////////////////////
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
```

I'm trying to get the buttons to light up under the dropdownlist and have the Label show on the same line as the buttons but on the left. (this code has the label on a new line because I gave up)

Comment: Use Css `padding/margin` attribute.

Comment: I've tried the margin by adding a margin to the buttons but still, when I run the form it pulls the buttons over because its almost as if it removes the label completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your controls in table cells , and fix the width of cells.

Nota : you can fix width with `css class`.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Style="position: relative;                             float: left; margin-left: 450px;" OnClientClick="parent.$.fancybox.close();" />
</td>

<td>
    <asp:Button ID="btnMoveCaseFile" runat="server" Text="" Style="position: relative;                             float: right; margin-right: 63px; margin-left: -45px; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 98px;"
                        OnClick="btnMoveCaseFile_Click" />
</td>

<td>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStatus"></asp:Label>                    
</td>
</tr>

</table>
```